# Design to change label color of TextInputLayout when calling on focus?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

here is my code

```
    emailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (!hasFocus) {
                    EditText txtUser = (EditText) v;
                    String userName = txtUser.getText().toString();
                    if (!userName.isEmpty()) {
                        if (!isvaliduser(userName)&&!isValidEmail(userName)) {
                            inputLayoutEmail.setHint("email/snipe id is required to login");
                        }
                    } else {
                        inputLayoutEmail.setHint("email / snipe ID");
//                        inputLayoutEmail.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.hintText);
                    }
                }

            }

        });
```

i want to apply hint color.here i am using set hint appearance.but its not working.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setHintTextColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHintTextColor(int)) instead.

```
inputLayoutEmail.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.black));
```

Comment: You can use `ContextCompat.getColor()` rather than `getResources().getColor()`. Also, mark my answer accepted if it resolves your issue. :)